# Trying to create a new .vue file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I tried to create the .vue file with the name of ChatMessage.vue which is inside the components directory , Directory structure is like this.

[image]

ChatMessage.vue has the same file contents which are present in Example.vue

Below are the references in resources/assets/js/app.js.

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-message', require('./components/ChatMessage.vue'));
```

**Below code shows the component**

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>Chat room</h1>
    <example></example>
</div>
```

**Below code does not show the component**

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>Chat room</h1>
    <chat-message></chat-message>
</div>
```

Am I missing anything? I just created the new Laravel project and then worked as mentioned above. That's it. Nothing else done so far in this new created project.

Please let me know if you need more info..

I never used gulp and this is my project structure. I can confirm that there is no gulp file:

[image]

Comment: Might be a silly question - have you run gulp/whatever build command after making the changes?

Comment: I never used gulp and this is my project structure. I can confirm that there is no gulp file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSddz.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to actually build your assets. First ensure the NPM dependencies are installed by running the `install` command.

```
$ npm install
```

Then you can build the assets with Laravel Mix.

```
$ npm run dev
```

If you'd like them to rebuild as you work on the project, swap `dev` for `watch`.

To compile all your assets you need to run npm install first to install all dependencies. take a look https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

Comment: After running the command `npm run dev` I am always js error at this line `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,` in public/app.js. It got resolved by commenting the line. May I know if this is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: just add this line `window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([ 'csrfToken' => csrf_token() ]) !!};` and in meta tag `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: May I ask that whenever I create a new laravel project...I will need to install npm in it? by running npm install and npm run dev to reflect the Vue component? Around 74MB files downloaded in the laravel project folder after running this command `npm install `

Comment: yes, to compile all your assets you need to run `npm install` first to install all dependencies. take a look https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

Comment: I just started to learn vue and I have no idea how to quickly compile the code. So far, I am using `npm run dev` in cmd prompt. Is there any other quicker way such that there is no need to open cmd prompt?